# Doubled input field when scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app which is basing heavily on our web app. When I try to scroll during editing input field the one that I'm focused gets doubled. It's not only visual glitch but the second input exists in dom. I'm using Ionic framework but combined with bootstrap and old code from web. When I installed Ionic demo app this problem doesn't exists so it must be something related to bootstrap but I don't have any idea what. If I knew I could deal with it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Some code would be awesome!

Comment: Try to remove bootstrap.js, shall be that is "doubling" your input field

Comment: What aorfevre said. You should never use 2 frameworks together.

Comment: My code as well as bootstrap.js has nothing to do with this issue. For now I'll overcome this problem just by turning on Ionic input stylesheets and removing those from bootstrap related to form but I'm more interested here not in how to fix it but the reason why it happens.